# How to fix node: bad option: --openssl-legacy-provider

Tags: reactjs

I started my react app with npm start but i got this
node: bad option: --openssl-legacy-provider
and i am using node v16.15.0
i tried deleting all the node modules and running npm install but it didnt work.

Comment: You should remove the `--openssl-legacy-provider` option.

Comment: Two way you could fix the issue:
1. by using node version 18 or up (in my case node 18.13.0 works fine)
2. by removing `--openssl-legacy-provider` from `npm start script`.

Answer (score 5):

By removing --openssl-legacy-provider option from your script, the problem will be resolved.

See https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/node-openssl-legacy-provider-is-not-allowed-in-node-options for further informations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: remove the option from where?

Comment: @Tims In the package.json

Answer (score 0):

In package.json file goto scripts find "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build", then change it to "build": "react-scripts build". This fixed my build issue.